# Google Tag Manager recreates the same tag in a Single Page App

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, progressive-web-apps

When navigating around in my SPA, I'm firing VirtualPageView events, but this is what the [Google Analytics debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) spits out:

[image]

It seems to be recreating the Google Analytics tag over and over. I'm not a GA expert, but from what I read, this is really bad for proper analysis. I think it has something to do with restarting the user session over and over?

The Google Tag Assistant seems to think the GTM itself is being recreated:

[image]

Things seem fine in the GTM preview console:

[image]

To emphasize my concern: The GA tag/tracker seems to be repeatedly recreated. Am I right? If so, how do I fix it?

---

For a reference, here's what I got configured in GTM:

[image]

The key functions that handle GTM events in my app are as follows:

```
const sendEvent = ({event, eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel}: GtmEvent): void =>
  send({
    event,
    eventCategory,
    eventAction,
    eventLabel,
    nonInteraction: false
  });

const sendVirtualPageView = (data: { url: string, title: string }): void =>
  send({
    event: <'VirtualPageView'>'VirtualPageView',
    virtualPageURL: data.url,
    virtualPageTitle: data.title,
  });


const send = (data: GtmEvent | VirtualPageView): void =>
  window.gtm.push(data);
```

Comment: There is nothing to fix, that's just how GTM works. The tracker is recreated for every tag.

Comment: @XTOTHEL you probably mean "for every event", right? Can you explain that? Or provide a resource? Can you explain why Google Tag Assistant reports those issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTM creates a new instance of the tracker object with a random name for every hit. While I do not have any official information I assume that is done to avoid hit scoped custom dimensions and other settings being automatically propagated to all GA tags, if you want them to or not (i.e. you might want to send different information for pageview tags and event tags). Also this avoids trackers overwriting each other if you track to more than one GA account.

If you want to have settings shared between GA tags you can now use the settings variable, and set anything specific to a tag directly in the tag settings.

So what you are seeing in the debugger just means that GTM is working as expected. as for Tag Assistant, while this is a potentially useful tool it gives an awful lot of false alarms, so use it with some caution.

Comment: Nice. Could you provide an explanation as clear as that, to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/118731/81324)?